# Flow Chart - Arrow

Tags: floats

i am now creating a flow chart like the one below. But, i have no idea how to adjust the whole chart in the middle of the page. (not on the top of the page) Also,any ideas on how to create the middle arrow like the graph below and how to add the wordings below the bottom arrow.(the wordings are too much for that) Thanks a lot, i appreciate for all helpful ideas.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%-----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eurosym}
%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, quotes, chains, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, text width=4cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=4cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process2} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=4cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process3} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=4cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process4} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=4cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{process5} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=4cm, draw=black, fill=orange!0]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw, very thick, color=black!75, -latex']
\tikzstyle{empty}=[]
%-----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=29.5cm, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm][scale=0.01,anchor=center]
\node (start) [startstop] {\footnotesize Employed Income \\ $<$ 59 400 \euro};
\node (pro2) [process, below = 10mm of start]{\footnotesize Employed Income \\ $>$ 59 400 \euro};
\node (pro1) [process2, below = 1mm of pro2]{\footnotesize Self-Employed};
\node (pro3) [process3, below = 1mm of pro1]{\footnotesize Civil Servants};
\node (pro4) [process4, right = 4cm of start]{\footnotesize SHI};
\node (pro5) [process5, right = 4cm of pro1]{\footnotesize PHI};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- node[anchor=south]{mandatory}(pro4);
\draw [arrow,dashed] (pro3.east) -- (pro5.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

your table has many issues:

for `tikzpicture`:

- for styles of image elements is used deprecated `tikzstyle`. instead it you should use `tizset` (see mwe below)
- styles are not consistent. all nodes' shapes are the same
- defined fill color is strange: `fill= orange!0` ? this is the same as `fill=white` ...
- why first you scale image down and then magnify by `adjustbox`?. far, far, better is draw image in natural size.
- font size newer define as you do: {\footnotesize text in the node}`. this lead to wrong line spaces in multi line text.
- if you define `minimum width` equal to `text width`, than `minimum width` is superfluous. it has sense, if it is larger than text width plus two `inner xsep`

for image center on the page:

- just omit figure's position option

beside this is more unclear tings. for example, why the page's borders are set to zero i if image is not so big, etc.

i suggest the following revision of your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%-----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eurosym}
%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
         > = Stealth,
box/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners,
              draw=#1, fill=#1!30, thick,
              text width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
lin/.style = {draw=gray, very thick},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize, align=left}
        }
%-----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%transform shape, scale=2, % use in case 
                                                   % when you like to enlarge image
node distance = 2mm and 44 mm
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[box/.default = olive]
\node (n1) [box]                    {Employed Income \\ $<$ 59 400 \euro};
\node (n2) [box, below=6mm of n1]   {Employed Income \\ $>$ 59 400 \euro};
\node (n3) [box, below=of n2]       {Self-Employed};
\node (n4) [box, below=of n3]       {Civil Servants};
%
\node (n5) [box, right=of n1]       {SHI};
\node (n6) [box, right=of n3]       {PHI};
    \end{scope}
%
\draw [lin,->] (n1)    to ["mandatory"]    (n5);
%
    \draw [lin]  (n2.east) -- ++ (0.5,0) |- (n3) coordinate[pos=0.25] (aux);
\draw [lin,->]   (aux) to ["choice"]  ++ (1.2,0) to (n5.south west);
\draw [lin,->]   (aux)                ++ (1.2,0) to (n6);
%
\draw [lin,->,dashed]  (n4.east) to ["Additional insurance\\
                                   (most healt care costs\\
                                   for civil servants are\\
                                   \dots" ',pos=0.2]  (n6);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

see if the result is close to what you like to obtain:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps and really learnt from it. appreciate a lot

Comment: @DanielChan, if you liked answer and find it useful, you can up-vote it (by clicking on up pen at top left side of answer) or even accept it (by clicking on check mark at same place)  :-)